# Is it possible to publish/subscribe as root?

Tags: ros, root, subscribe, publish

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello smart people,

I have made a ROS node that makes use of an FTDI library that requires that I run the executable as root to have access to the usb device that the node reads data from. The trouble with running the executable as a super user is that it prevents me from being able to see the roscore master because root uses a different environment and I can't seem to export the ROS master URI location to root's environment variables. Has anyone figured out how to publish/subscribe to rostopics when running a node as a super user?

P.S. Changing permissions on the usb device is not something I think I can do to solve this because FTDI's instructions for use of this library is that I remove the modules that would have the device show up in the /dev/ folder (i.e. rmmod ftdi_sio & rmmod usbserial)

Thanks for the help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239105/is-it-possible-to-publish/subscribe-as-root?/) by [wmrifenb](https://answers.ros.org/users/27428/wmrifenb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-07-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2016-07-08**:
If that's an option, just source the ROS installation and workspaces (as superuser), so that the environment variables will be set. The easiest way would be to actually login as superuser (e.g. `sudo su` in Ubuntu) and then source the normal user's `.bashrc` (if it's set up with ROS stuff)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, that should work.

However, setting the permissions is the better way. udev should work, or just adding yourself to the dialout group.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2016-07-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [wmrifenb](https://answers.ros.org/users/27428/wmrifenb/) on 2016-07-08**:
This doesn't really answer my question. Adding myself to the dialout group wont work because the device is removed from the /dev/ folder upon removal of the modules I mentioned. What I really want to know is how to get a node that is running under root to talk to the ros master

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2016-07-11**:
There shouldn't be any difference. Just treat root as another ros user.